# Class not working, Error occured?

Tags: android, dropbox

I am using Android 2.1 platform.Going to do one project based on DropBox.I used the DBUtility class for listing contacts in DropBox. DBUtility is not a main class.It is a sub Class.Main class calls some functions from this class.

It was working well seperately,The Createfolder() on the below code contains only one statement

**mDBApi.createFolder("Contacts");**

There was no error as mentioned above.when I added some code based on the **Contact**.I got the error like

**"The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type DropBoxUtility"**.

**Code**

```
public class DropBoxUtility {
    private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;  
    public DropBoxUtility(DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> Api) {
        mDBApi = Api;  
    } 

    public void ContactFolder() throws DropboxException { 
        mDBApi.createFolder("Contacts");
        ArrayAdapter<String>itemAdapter;
        ArrayList<String> contactlist = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        String displayName="All Contacts Here";
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(displayName.getBytes());
        Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("Contacts/abhi.doc", inputStream, displayName.length(), null, null);    

        /* I got Error on this line */
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver() ;
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            displayName = ""; 
            displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String holder = "";
            holder = holder + displayName;

            /* Phone Number and Type */
            ArrayList<String> phoneList = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                int phoneType = pCur
                        .getInt(pCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                String pnum = pCur.getString(pCur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                switch (phoneType) {
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                    phoneList.add(", Home, "+pnum);
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                    phoneList.add(", Work, "+pnum);
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                    phoneList.add(", Mobile, "+pnum);
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                    phoneList.add(", Other, "+pnum);
                    break;
                }
            }   // end of while

            pCur.close(); 
        }       // end of if

        /* Email */
        Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, null, Email.CONTACT_ID
                + " = " + id, null, null);

        ArrayList<String> emailList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (emails.moveToNext()) {
            int emailType = emails
                    .getInt(emails
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
            String email = emails.getString(emails
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

            switch (emailType) {
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME:
                emailList.add(", Home, "+email);
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK:
                emailList.add(", Work, "+email);
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_MOBILE:
                emailList.add(", Mobile, "+email);
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_OTHER:
                emailList.add(", Other, "+email);
                break;
            }
        }
        emails.close();


        if(phoneList.size()>=emailList.size()) {
            for(int i=0;i<phoneList.size();i++) {
                holder = displayName + phoneList.get(i);
                try{
                    holder = holder + emailList.get(i);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    holder = holder + ", , ";
                }
                contactlist.add(holder);
            }
        }else {
            for(int i=0;i<emailList.size();i++) {
                try{
                    holder = displayName+ phoneList.get(i);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    holder = holder + ", , ";
                }
                holder = holder + emailList.get(i);
                contactlist.add(holder);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(contactlist);
    cursor.close(); 

}
```

**Logcat**

```
 07-05 14:57:54.734: W/dalvikvm(392): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
 07-05 14:57:54.734: E/AndroidRuntime(392): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 07-05 14:57:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(392): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts from pid=392, uid=10028 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
 07-05 14:57:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1218)
 07-05 14:57:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
 07-05 14:57:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
 07-05 14:57:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQuery(ContentProviderNative.java:326)
 07-05 14:57:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:345)
 07-05 14:57:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:202)
 07-05 14:57:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     at com.abhi.DropBoxUtility.ContactFolder(DropBoxUtility.java:47)
```

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getContentResolver` method is present in `Context` class.  You can call it directly from an activity, because Activity is a Context.  Your `DropBoxUtility` is not an `Activity`, therefore you need to have a context in it to use `getContentResolver` method.  The easiest thing is to pass it to the constructor:

```
public class DropBoxUtility
{
    private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;
    private Context context;

    public DropBoxUtility(DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> Api, Context ctx)
    {
        mDBApi = Api;
        context = ctx;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, when you need to make the call, use `context.getContentResolver()`.

You would instantiate this class from your activity as `new DropBoxUtility(api, this);`

**EDIT:** to read contact information, you need to add corresponding permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: @Hari Did you change the definition of `DropBoxUtility` class and constructor as I showed you?  Where are you instantiating the class from?  It mist be done from an activity or some place where `context` is available.

Comment: I edit my code to ...mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session); 
  mDbUtility = new DropBoxUtility(mDBApi);

  mDbUtility = new DropBoxUtility(mDBApi, this);

  setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: It is working now.but Application stopped unexpectedly..I posted the logcat errors

Comment: @Hari read the exception carefully: you need to add permissions to your manifest.  I updated my answer, but you need to do the work yourself before throwing things onto SO.  2 minutes on google would have given you the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I am very Beginner to this Android, I am learning Stackoverflow also. That is why I am asking.Don;t take me in otherwise. Anyway the answer you gave me is correct. So I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// I got Error on this line     ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver() ;
```

I have no idea for **DropBox api**, but surely I can point out this error, is `getContentResolver()` is a method of android **Activity** class not for **DropBoxUtility**, you can use this method in different class using the **context(reference) of that activity**.

Pass the context of Android Activity to DropBoxUtility constructor and use that context
like,

```
ContentResolver cr =  mContext.getContentResolver(); // Here mContext is a reference of your Activity class from which your are calling this DropBox class.
```

Try this,

Answer (score 0):

The class `DropBoxUtility` does not inherit from any class that provides the `getContentResolver` method (i.e `Activity`). Either you have to derive the class from another class or you have to declare and implement the `getContentResolver` method.

As user370305 says, you can pass an instance of `Activity` to the constructor of your `DropBoxUtility` class and call the method on that instance.